# Calculate the sum of values from certain keys in nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a shopping cart object, e.g:

```
  const shopCart = {
    "4509563079435": {
      name: "product 1",
      price: 29.99,
      quantity: 2,
      subtotal: 59.98,
    },
    "5678327300382": {
      name: "product 2",
      price: 90.49,
      quantity: 1,
      subtotal: 90.49,
    },
    "8612061865613": {
      name: "product 3",
      price: 58.99,
      quantity: 2,
      subtotal: 117.98,
    },
  };
```

The item IDs could be anything, there could be any number of items.

I want to sum all the subtotals to arrive at a total for this cart and save the in a variable.

I know how to do this with a flat object (reduce or sum) but I'm having trouble iterating the nested items.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out myself only a minute after posting here :)

```js
  const shopCart = {
    "4509563079435": {
      name: "product 1",
      price: 29.99,
      quantity: 2,
      subtotal: 59.98,
    },
    "5678327300382": {
      name: "product 2",
      price: 90.49,
      quantity: 1,
      subtotal: 90.49,
    },
    "8612061865613": {
      name: "product 3",
      price: 58.99,
      quantity: 2,
      subtotal: 117.98,
    },
  };

 const total = Object.values(shopCart).reduce((acc, curr) => (acc = acc + curr["subtotal"]), 0);

 console.log(total);
```

I need to use Object.values, which returns an array of all the items.
Then the reduce method can sum the values from the indicated key.

Hope this helps anyone who was stuck for a while like me :)